# Mac WebStorm Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm on a ReactNative project and prefer to use airbnb. I have npm install airbnb global:

1. `npm install -g airbnb` (and also dependencies)
2. Made `.eslintrc` file with config "extends": `eslint-config-airbnb`
3. WebStorm enabled ESLint and use above `.eslintrc`

Got error below:

> Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb'

Other info:

- MacOS
- WebStorm 2017.1.2

Comment: I think you need to run `npm install` on `eslint-config-airbnb` (rather than `airbnb`) and your `eslint.rc` file should `extend` the `airbnb` ruleset rather than the `eslint-config-airbnb` ruleset.

Answer (score 12):

Plugin and eslint needs to be installed at the same location ie if eslint s global then plugin need to be global and if its local then both need to be local.

With that Webstorm uses local version of eslint and not global (thats how at least work on windows). So make sure you install eslint and plugin locally using `npm install`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: One question here - is there a way to configure webstorm to automatically find eslint local package or you have to change the path manually each time you swap your project in webstorm?

Comment: This also applies to PHPStorm (and perhaps to other JetBrains IDEs).